# Dynamically add validation observables using rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to write an obervable for validation task. I have 2 observables that I want to process in order, `frontEndValidate` and `backEndValidate`. If one throws an error, the pipeline should stop. These 2 observables will be emitted at runtime when I click `validate` button, by calling `next()` inside `validate()`.

In the pipeline i check if the emitted obervables is valid, if so continue, else throw an error.

This pipeline works fine if those 2 observable emit `of({ valid: true})`. But if  it emits `of({valid:false})`, my `validationAction$` wil be dead and the `validate` button will not work.

I also cannot use `catchError` to keep the pipeline alive, sine the validation will continue no matter what state of the observable is.

For short, I want my pipeline to behave like this and still alive.

1. Case valid, valid => from([true,true])
2. Case valid, invalid => from([true, false])
3. Case invalid => from([false])

Thank you.

### Pipeline

```
private validationSubject = new Subject<Observable<any>>();
validationAction$ = this.validationSubject.asObservable().pipe(
    concatMap((item) =>
        from(item)
            .pipe(
                map((result) => {
                    console.log("result", result);
                    if (!result.valid) throw new Error();
                    return result
                }),
            )
    ),
);
```

### onClick

```
validate() {
    this.validationSubject.next(this.frontEndValidate());
    this.validationSubject.next(this.backEndValidate());
}
```

### 2 Observables

```
/* Front-end validation */
/** */
frontEndValidate(): Observable < any > {
    // Validation goes here

    return of({ valid: true, name: 'frontend', msg: 'Passed' }).pipe(
        tap(() => {
            console.log('frontend validation...starts');
        }),
        delay(3000), // mimic delay
        tap(() => {
            console.log('frontend validation...finished')
        }),
    );
}

/* Back-end validation */
/** */
backEndValidate(): Observable < any > {
    // Validation goes here 

    return of({ valid: true, name: 'backend', msg: 'Passed' }).pipe(
        tap(() => {
            console.log('backend validation...starts');
        }),
        delay(3000), // mimic delay
        tap(() => {
            console.log('backend validation...finished')
        }),
    );
}
```

Comment: If you want only validation result then why are you throwing error.Instead of throwing error,just return data

Comment: If error occurs in the first validation i want it to stop running

Comment: are `pipeLine` and `onCick` both code chunk in same file?By asking this I am trying to figure it out ,that can we implement your problem without subject?

Comment: As @Saptarsi said, if you throw an unhandled error from an Observable, that Observable is "dead" and you won't be able to validate again without refreshing the application. So you'll need to return data (such as a false value) and not throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
  validate() {
    const result$ = combineLatest([
      this.frontEndValidate(),
      this.backEndValidate(),
    ])
      .pipe(
        tap(([frontEndResult, backEndResult]) => {
          // Do whatever else here
        })
      );

    result$.subscribe(x => console.log('Result: ', JSON.stringify(x)));
  }
```

Then you don't need the subject. Just use `combineLatest` to combine the two results and ensure the code that follows it waits for both to complete before continuing.

The result emits an array with the two objects defined in your validation methods. To instead emit only an array with the Boolean values, try this:

```
  validate() {
    const result$ = combineLatest([
      this.frontEndValidate(),
      this.backEndValidate(),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([frontEndResult, backEndResult]) => 
        ([frontEndResult.valid, backEndResult.valid])
      )
    );

    result$.subscribe((x) => console.log('Result: ', JSON.stringify(x)));
  }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-validation-deborahk

Comment: Your code works as great! Btw, I'm a big and of you. I've learned a lot from your Angular courses. This really made my day :D

Comment: But what I want is I want to validate things in order (something like concatmap). If frontEndValidate fails, then no need to run backEndValidate.

Comment: I've forked your example and modified some codes. All I want is `validationResult`. But I don't want to do it this way (use variable). I just want it all done in `result$` . Here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-validation-deborahk-mynnhi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Based on your "if frontEndValidate fails, then no need to run backEndValidate", I modified your code. The change is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-validation-deborahk Is that getting closer?